# What free space thresholds/limits are advisable for 640 GB and 2 TB hard disk drives with ZEVO ZFS on OS X?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-space, osx-mountain-lion, zfs

Assuming that free space advice for [ZEVO](http://zevo.getgreenbytes.com) will not differ from advice for other modern implementations of ZFS …

## Question

Please, what *percentages* or *amounts* of free space are advisable for hard disk drives of the following sizes?

- 640 GB
- 2 TB

### Thoughts

A standard answer for modern implementations of ZFS might be "no more than 96 percent full". However if apply that to (say) a single-disk 640 GB dataset where some of the files most commonly used (by VirtualBox) are **larger than 15 GB each**, then I guess that blocks for those files will become **sub optimally spread** across the platters with around **26 GB free**.

I read that in most cases, fragmentation and defragmentation should not be a concern with ZFS. Sill, I like the mental picture of most fragments of a large .vdi in reasonably close proximity to each other. (Do features of ZFS make that wish for proximity too old-fashioned?)

Side note: there might arise the question of how to optimise performance (for massive files  in a dataset with relatively little free space) *after* a threshold is 'broken'. If it arises, I'll keep it separate.

### Background

On a 640 GB StoreJet Transcend (product ID 0x2329) in the past I probably went beyond an advisable threshold. Currently the largest file is around 17 GB –

[image]

– and I doubt that any .vdi or other file on this disk will grow beyond 40 GB. (Ignore the purple masses, those are bundles of 8 MB *band* files.)

Without HFS Plus: the thresholds of [twenty](http://pondini.org/TM/30.html), ten and five percent that I associate with Mobile Time Machine file system need not apply.

I currently use ZEVO Community Edition 1.1.1 with Mountain Lion, OS X 10.8.2, but I'd like answers to be not too version-specific.

#### References, chronological order

[ZFS Block Allocation (Jeff Bonwick's Blog)](https://blogs.oracle.com/bonwick/entry/zfs_block_allocation) (2006-11-04)

[Space Maps (Jeff Bonwick's Blog)](https://blogs.oracle.com/bonwick/entry/space_maps) (2007-09-13)

[Doubling Exchange Performance (Bizarre ! Vous avez dit Bizarre ?)](https://blogs.oracle.com//roch/entry/doubling_exchange_performance) (2010-03-11)

> … So to solve this problem, what went in 2010/Q1 software release is
>   multifold. The most important thing is: we increased the threshold at
>   which we switched from 'first fit' (go fast) to 'best fit' (pack
>   tight) from 70% full to 96% full. With TB drives, each slab is at
>   least 5GB and 4% is still 200MB plenty of space and no need to do
>   anything radical before that. This gave us the biggest bang. Second,
>   instead of trying to reuse the same primary slabs until it failed an
>   allocation we decided to stop giving the primary slab this
>   preferential threatment as soon as the biggest allocation that could
>   be satisfied by a slab was down to 128K
>   (`metaslab_df_alloc_threshold`). At that point we were ready to switch
>   to another slab that had more free space. We also decided to reduce
>   the SMO bonus. Before, a slab that was 50% empty was preferred over
>   slabs that had never been used. In order to foster more write
>   aggregation, we reduced the threshold to 33% empty. This means that a
>   random write workload now spread to more slabs where each one will
>   have larger amount of free space leading to more write aggregation.
>   Finally we also saw that slab loading was contributing to lower
>   performance and implemented a slab prefetch mechanism to reduce down
>   time associated with that operation.
>
> The conjunction of all these changes lead to 50% improved OLTP and 70%
>   reduced variability from run to run …

[OLTP Improvements in Sun Storage 7000 2010.Q1 (Performance Profiles)](https://blogs.oracle.com/dlutz/entry/oltp_improvements_in_2010_q1) (2010-03-11)

[Alasdair on Everything » ZFS runs *really* slowly when free disk usage goes above 80%](http://blogs.everycity.co.uk/alasdair/2010/07/zfs-runs-really-slowly-when-free-disk-usage-goes-above-80/) (2010-07-18) where commentary includes:

> … OpenSolaris has changed this in onnv revision 11146 …

[[CFT] Improved ZFS metaslab code (faster write speed)](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-current/2010-August/019346.html) (2010-08-22)

Comment: https://github.com/pcbsd/pcbsd/commit/714a2ccf0b19188dd2c41d44f15181e5e46ce7f3#diff-730a706a1ae0e533b9d17f784cb40a93L1274 notes that crankiness may occur over **seventy-five** percent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Eighty percent full (twenty percent free)

http://www.ustream.tv/recorded/25859777 audible around 33:00 on the timeline, in response to [Eric Sproul's case](https://superuser.com/a/484221/84988):

> … the Delphix product … to the user was eighty percent. So, I mean a lot of it depends on the workload but we would definitely … I think four percent would be *extreme* for any …

> … **And** performance would suck.

– sounds like [Matt Ahrens](http://blog.delphix.com/matt/) (moderating) at the 2012 Illumos [ZFS Day](http://zfsday.com/zfsday/).

Plus: recently rediscovered by me, from two years ago:

- [Oracle Solaris ZFS Performance: 10 Easy Tips](http://constantin.glez.de/blog/2010/04/ten-ways-easily-improve-oracle-solaris-zfs-filesystem-performance) (2010-04-28)

Under [**#8 Leave Enough Free Space**](http://constantin.glez.de/blog/2010/04/ten-ways-easily-improve-oracle-solaris-zfs-filesystem-performance#freespace):

> … As a rule of thumb, don't let your pool become more full than about
>   80% of its capacity. Once it reaches that point, you should start
>   adding more disks so ZFS has enough free blocks to choose from in
>   sequential write order.

Answer (score 0):

## Around eighty-five percent full (fifteen percent free)

http://www.ustream.tv/recorded/25859777 around 32:20 on the timeline:

> … four percent free? … That seems … a little close to the edge. We try to aim for about eighty-five percent full before we start thinking about expanding capacity or doing something to relieve that pressure … we're pretty conservative …

Then around 33:20, in response to the [eighty percent commentary](https://superuser.com/a/484224/84988):

> Yeah, if you tried to do *this* on a system that was ninety-six percent full, you'd probably run out of space before you got done whatever you were doing … because the space would accumulate; and having that snapshot present would hold on to data that would otherwise be freed back to the pool from the normal activity …

> … **And** performance would suck. Because ZFS works on a slab allocator … if you get really full, you start having to spend extra time finding places to fit different sizes of things, and it gets really slow.

– [Eric Sproul](http://omniti.com/is/eric-sproul) at the 2012 Illumos [ZFS Day](http://zfsday.com/zfsday/).